# How to check if nodes are connect at all in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph in Neo4j (first time using it) of about 10 different nodes that are connected in various ways. Not all nodes are connected to each other, as some have up to 6 or 7 neighbors, while some have only 1. What query would I write/use to check if a path exists from NodeA to NodeB? It doesn't have to be the shortest path, just if a path exists.

Along with this, is there a way to count who has the most or least neighbors? Thanks everyone for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Return `Foo` nodes `a` and `b` if there is at least one path between them. (This variable-length path query with unbounded length could take a very long time or run out of memory if there are a lot of paths or very long paths).

   ```
   MATCH (a:Foo {id: 'a'}), (b:Foo {id: 'b'})
   WHERE (a)-[*]-(b)
   RETURN a, b;
   ```
2. Return all paths between `a` and `b`. (This query could require even more time and memory than the previous query, since it will attempt to return all matching paths).

   ```
   MATCH path=(a:Foo {id: 'a'})-[*]-(b:Foo {id: 'b'})
   RETURN path;
   ```
3. Return the 10 nodes with the most neighbors, in descending order:

   ```
   MATCH (n)--()
   WITH n, COUNT(*) AS c
   RETURN n
   ORDER BY c DESC
   LIMIT 10;
   ```